# Is StackStatus on Twitter maintained?

Tags: support, status-review, server-maintenance, stack-status

Yesterday when I tried to log in to Stack Overflow, it was down with the message

> Stack Overflow is currently offline for maintenance

The first sentence under the title suggested to check with [@StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus) on Twitter, yet when I went there, it seemed that account hadn't been updated in months. Is it still operational?

If it’s not maintained anymore, could the message be updated to remove references to it?

Comment: I know they moved to https://www.stackstatus.net/ and the [incident from yesterday was logged there in real time](https://www.stackstatus.net/incidents/1423d5c8-7846-4474-9f09-1f38cc13d67b). The new status page *is* linked in the @StackStatus account's bio. Though, I don't recall if they've decided to stop using that account.

Comment: It's possible the @StackStatus account was included in the bots that [Catija mentioned were no longer supported as of 8 Feb 2023](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/386476/1099857).

Comment: I'll status review this since it would require a staff response to know for sure. I can't find anything network-wide that indicates that they've stopped supporting the twitter account. In fact, the last thing I can find is that they automated the process ["as of May 2022"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376038/1099857) but there are no visible tweets since August 2022.

Comment: @ThomA There were other ones later in 2022. I assume you aren't logged into Twitter, and Elon Musk in his infinite wisdom apparently decided people who aren't logged in should see posts sorted by popularity instead of date for some reason.

Comment: I was on my phone at the time, so it opened in browser not app @JohnMontgomery . You're right, that's a stupid order. It's like ordering answers by Accepted first and then most recented edited.

Comment: Upvote for still calling it Twitter. There is only so much infinite Musk wisdom that can be safely absorbed.